# Receiving messages from all/multiple the queues from JMS server

Tags: spring, jms, message-queue

I want loop all the queues in MQ server and log the messages.
For this trying to generate destinations dynamically.

I am using SpringBoot and @JmsListener(destination = "Regulatory_*").
Tried substituting destination with EL, with bean property injection,*.
Some how not able to get it working.

Is it possible some how or the requirement itself seems to be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

a message on a queue is, by design, meant for one consumer only. If you also want to log messages someplace else, it's a good reason to switch to JMS topics instead. Then you simply setup a second consumer that does nothing but log the messages.

Which JMS Provider are you using ? ActiveMQ ? Usually a JMS provider has some way of 'bridging' destinations which is another way of creating duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for feedback.I am using SpringJMS / ActiveMQ .I will check the possibility of Topic.But the application sends messages to specific queue and I have to log each meaasge in the queue.I have more than 100 queues here.